# Error loading font with watermark codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, fonts, watermark

Could anyone help me. I am trying to create a watermark but have a problem loading the font.
When I use the wm_font_path function the watermark does not appear on the image.
When I don't use the wm_font_path function the watermark appears with the system default font.

Another thing is that the wm_font_size function doesn't work properly because I can't increase the font size.

```
$image_data                 = $this->upload->data();
$config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
$config['source_image']     = $image_data['full_path'];
$config['wm_type']          = 'text';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
//$config['wm_vrt_offset']    = '300';
$config['wm_text']          = $nome;
$config['wm_font_path']     = './media/fonts/unineuebold.ttf';
$config['wm_font_size']     = 60;
$config['wm_font_color']    = '#4a4a4a';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Has anyone had this problem?

PHP Version 7.3

Answer (score 0):

You're using `'./media/fonts/unineuebold.ttf';`

So directory level should be like this

```
application
media
 - fonts
    - unineuebold.ttf 
system
tests
```

Comment: Hello, the directory level is correct. Still the source is not loaded

Comment: then make sure the font is valid. and if u r testing in LIVE check whether its placed or moved correctly